# Vkontakte Api: записи со стен пабликов.

Tags: vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте.

Где можно найти информацию о получении записей со стен пабликов? В документации самого вконтакта я ничего толком не нашёл по этому поводу... В общем - подкиньте ссылок пожалуйста. А если это вообще невозможно средствами API Вконтакте, то объясните в двух словах, по какому принципу сделаны приложения под мобильные ОС.

Заранее большое спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запросы к стене паблика выполняются так-же, как и [запросы на стену пользователя](http://userapi.ru/?act=doc#wall), только перед **`id`** *паблика* ставится "**`-`**".

---

##### Запись на стене группы ВК "*User API*":

> [http://vk.com/wall**-**1_1](http://vk.com/wall-1_1)

##### Запись на стене Павла Дурова:

> http://vk.com/wall1_1

Comment: Спасибо. Группы - стены... Сбили с толку :)